# Layout of module for Admin is not loaded

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, layout, module, adminhtml

my `config.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
   <modules>
        <Octane_SMTP>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Octane_SMTP>
   </modules>
    <frontend>
     .............
    </frontend>
    <admin>
     <routers>
         <SMTP>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
               <module>Octane_SMTP</module>
               <frontName>adminSMTP</frontName>
            </args>
        </SMTP>
    </routers>
 </admin>
 <adminhtml>
   <layout>
      <updates>
          <SMTP>
              <file>SMTP.xml</file>
          </SMTP>
      </updates>
   </layout>
   <menu>
      <SMTP translate="title" module="Adminhtml">
         <title>My plugins</title>
         <sort_order>100</sort_order>
         <children>
             <set_time>
                   <title>Address book</title>
                   <action>adminSMTP/adminhtml_index</action>
              </set_time>
          </children>
       </SMTP>
    </menu>
</adminhtml>
   <global>
     <blocks>
         <SMTP>
              <class>Octane_SMTP_Block</class>
         </SMTP>
      </blocks>
         <helpers>
              <SMTP>
                   <class>Octane_SMTP_Helper</class>
              </SMTP>
         </helpers>
<models>
 ..........

</global>
</config>
```

my layout file SMTP.xml which is located at app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout

and controller file which is located at

```
app/code/local/Octane/SMTP/controllers/Adminhtml

class Octane_SMTP_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
    {
    public function indexAction()
          {
             echo"show something plz.....";
             $this->loadlayout();
             //$this->renderLayout();
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Dev mode on
2. cache off
3. Check whether the XML is loaded: make an error in it, reload, should throw an error
4. make sure the layout handle is correct -> add

   ```
   $this->loadLayout();
   var_dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdates()->getHandles())
   ```

   to your controller

layout file looks good.

Layout handle should be: `SMTP_index_index`, node of your frontename, name of the controller, name of the action.